# Asp.net Gridview is Crashing when I load 25000 records into it

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am loading 25000 records into my gridview with 70 Columns and it is crashing.

Why is it crashing?

Comment: Please post your error message

Comment: What error message  do you get?

Comment: Problem 1: "I am loading 25000 records into my gridview with 70 Columns".  When is a user going to scroll through 25,000 items in a gridview. It's simply not good UI design.

Comment: What is crashing? IE? Firefox? What browser are you using when the crash occurs? Like the others mentioned post your error message.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's 2011, it's common sense to NOT load 25k records into a single screen.

Comment: it doesn't give any error just never responds..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gridviews are known to cause an out-of-memory exception when displaying tens of thousands of rows (1.7 million cells, in your case).

- Out of Memory [Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809968/system-outofmemoryexception-when-binding-a-gridview-to-a-datatable-having-more-th)
- You should use [paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging.aspx).
- [Custom Fast Paging](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)
- [Paging with LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx)

You may consider setting EnableViewState to False; that is, if you don't plan on allowing editing.

If your application requires you to write 25k results to the screen and you are constrained from using paging, then you should probably be emitting text to the screen via dumping the contents of a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) into a [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx), rather than using a Gridview.

With that said, everything points to a broken design. There are very few legitimate reasons to dump that many records into a webpage.

Comment: thanks for the info.. I am displaying an Excel Document in a gridview.. It almost doesn't make sense to pagify it.

Comment: you might be able to achieve a nice compromise w/ a large page-size

Comment: your answer works, what i did was give a sample of the issue in the excel file.  i will consider pagifying it another time Thanks